# How to rename multiple file names through Ms-dos command

Tags: batch-file, dos

How to add a String (100000) to multiple file names through Ms-dos command.

I have multiple files (customer,address,postal_area..etc) stored in single folder. I want to add 100000 string to these file names like below..

```
100000_customer.txt
100000_address.txt
100000_posrtal_area.txt
```

how to do this one with single dos command? Is it possible?

Many thhanks for your help.

Sunitha.

Comment: Hope this will help lot.
http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in cmd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271586/rename-multiple-files-in-cmd)

Comment: There is no MS-DOS anymore. I guess you really mean the Windows command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command

```
ren "*.txt" "100000_*.txt"
```

Comment: This command will replace the starting characters in file name like '100000_r.txt', '100000__area.txt'. Is there a way not to do that?

Answer (score -1):

I successfully rename my images files names with *.1

See my command below:
    `ren "*.1" "*.jpg"`

all the files chnaged to .jpg file extension.