# Rename Multiple files at once in dos

Tags: file, cmd, rename

I have a large data set that all starts with VDC_ and followed with 5 digits.
ex: VDC_21556 , VDC_21580 and so on. ( 10000 files)

I'd like to remove the VDC_ from the filenames just leaving it with numbers

Any tip ?

Comment: Are you really using MS-DOS or are you referring to the command line in Windows?

Comment: These are invalid filenames for DOS, so it definitively is `cmd`. Edited the tags.

Comment: Did you search before asking? Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26602633/6607497

Answer (score 0):

If you can use powershell then the following line should do it:

dir | rename-item -NewName {$*.name -replace "VDC*",""}

Cheers,

Neil

Comment: or even "VDC_", ""

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Save the following as RASPfile.cmd in the same folder as the vlc_#####'s then double click it</strike>

There is a way simpler method, see my second attempt below.

1st attempt

```
@echo off
:: Rename And Shorten Placement of file names
:: Not all are essential, but if you don't know, play failsafe
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

:: Extension.less files are difficult to handle thus make them all.eXt@end
Ren VDC_????? VDC_?????.X

:: FORFILES cmd /c is logical to use but reputedly throttles incrementally towards 10,000 files !!
:: so KISS (Keep It Stupidly Simples) a 1 liner
FOR %%F IN ("*.X") DO set name=%%F&ren %%F !name:~4,5!& echo !name:~4,5!
```

**2nd attempt**

**Simply in each folder just run**

```
ren "VDC_*.*" "////*.*"
```

based on https://superuser.com/a/871799