# Renaming files in one format to the other

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch of files named in the following format

> STR1_xxxxxxxxxx_STR2.txt

I would like to remove the xxxxxxxxxx part.

That is to rename into

> STR1_STR2.txt

**UPDATE**:

To make it simple, consider STR1 as a random string with random length which we dont know. It may also include the character "_".

STR2 is a string we know.

xxxxxxxxxxxx is a random string with fixed length, it is also the part I want to remove.

Comment: Check out the following way:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271586/rename-multiple-files-in-cmd

Comment: @Vanest Thanks but this doesnt do the stuff...

Comment: Per update, name could be STR1xxxxxxxxxxxx_STR2, no _ in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test.bat**

```
@echo off
set file=STR1_xxxxxxxxxx_STR2.txt
set file2=%file:*_=%
for /f "delims=_" %%a in ("%file%") do set file1=%%a
set file1=%file1%_%file2:*_=%
ren %file% %file1%
```

Try this. Place this batch file where you have text file.

**UPDATED**

Now try this

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set file=STR1_2_xxxxxxxxxx_STR2.txt
call :reverse %file% file1
for /f "delims=_" %%a in ("%file1%") do set file2=%%a
set file1=%file1:*_=%
set file1=%file1:*_=%
call :reverse %file1% file3
call :reverse %file2% file4
set file1=%file3%_%file4%
set file1=%file1: =%
ren %file% %file1%
goto :eof

:reverse
set str=%~1
set cnt=0
:loop
if "%str%" equ "" (
    goto :eof
    )
set chr=!str:~0,1!
set str=%str:~1%
set %2=%chr%!%2! 
goto loop
```

Comment: Thanks but we have "_" in STR1.

Comment: @Kumar Can you explain your code a little at bottom of answer. I'd like to understand it better. It looks like you're setting the file name to always be literal "STR1_2_xxxxxxxxxx_STR2.txt" but I assume this acts as a pattern in some way. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sure... He said that first string(say STR1_2) may also contain '_'. So we can't predict how many '_' occur in the first string but we know about other strings. So i just reverse the string then finding first and second occurence of '_' to split and join the first(STR1_2) and last(STR2) string then reverse it. Hope you could understand.

Comment: Ah...so you read it from right to left! Very clever. Good info to have. Thx