# Renaming multiple files in Windows

Tags: powershell, cmd, window

I have a folder containing multiple .txt files which have been created by another program. However the program outputs each file with "-Module" in the
filename. eg

```
filename-Module.txt
filename1-Module.txt
filename2-Module.txt
```

I would like to know if there's a script or command (Powershell/cmd) that I can run which will iterate over each file and remove the "-Module" from each filename so I simply end up with

```
filename.txt
filename1.txt
filename2.txt
```

I have tried using cmd from the directory, with the following:

```
rename *-Module.txt *txt
```

This resulted in no change.

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? Please share your efforts; [edit] your question for that...

Comment: Might be able to find your answer here https://superuser.com/questions/236820/how-do-i-remove-the-same-part-of-a-file-name-for-many-files-in-windows-7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271586/rename-multiple-files-in-cmd)

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I am really only beginning to try and learn PS/cmd so I appreciate the feedback and direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use get-childitem and pipe it into rename-item.

```
    get-childitem -path 'c:\folderwherefilesarelocated' -recurse |
    rename-item -newname {$_.Name -replace "-module", ""}
```

Comment: The bit after `'-module'` isn't actually necessary to remove the text

Comment: Thanks MattMoo . This took care of things nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Relatively straightforward:

```
Get-ChildItem ComputerName\TestLocation\testfolder -filter "*-module*" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '-module', ''}
```

Get the items in the folder, look for filenames with "-module" in them, and then replace the "-module" text with an empty string. You can also append a `-whatif` to see the output before performing this action.